# On being created in pairs

Tags: nikah

It is said in Islam that we are made in pairs. Then why do many end up living their lives alone? My beautiful and highly educated aunt remains unmarried till today. We all did our best to arrange a good marriage for her but could not succeed. She has been a pious woman her whole life and never engaged in relationship. She is tired now and refuses to met any other prospective groom. It is highly unlikely for her to married especially now since she is approaching 50. I do wonder, whether we lost something in translation or something we could not understand properly about "being created in pair". Will love to know opinions of my brothers and sisters here and educate myself in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why people don’t get married sometimes is they have strong criteria , they reject potential partners that was available for them. . It is highly recommended to get married but people make their own choices . They prioritize other aspects of their life such as education or career meanwhile all these aspects are achievable when you have husband or wife. They also don’t want to marry divorcees or they want to marry financially strong people. They prioritize physical attributes more than how someone’s character is. The list goes on ...

When Allah talks about we made you in pairs , it is talking about men and women. Union and each of them completing each other.
It is not Allahs error that people don’t get married but perhaps choices of both male and female.

Comment: Thank you brother, especially for letting me think about this in a different perspective. May Allah bless you.